# Match number between characters

Tags: regex

Here is some examples 158811_**23**.jpg  151_**188**.gif

How to match the number between `_` and `.jpg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fairly simple regular expression should match the number you need as the first group:

```
[0-9]*_([0-9])*\.(?:jpg|gif)
```

It works for both .jpg and .gif files, since you used both in your examples.

Comment: you'll probably want to do `([0-9]+)` instead of `([0-9])*`

Comment: but it's getting only the last number ex. 158811_23.jpg (i want 23 not 3). Bark is correct it's ([0-9]+) instead of ([0-9])

Answer (score 7):

If you want to match the numbers between `_` and `.jpg` but **exclude** the `_` and `.jpg` then use:

`(?<=\_)[0-9]+(?=\.jpg)`

`(?<=\\_)` is called a ***lookbehind***. Anything after the `_` except the `_`

`(?=\\.jpg)` is called a ***lookahead***. Anything before the `.jpg` excluding the `.jpg`

Answer (score 4):

Use this to segregate your numbers into the group $1 gif etc. are in $2

`_(\d+)\.(gif|jpg)`